# Custom Android App Store?

Tags: android, installation, google-play

I have a question. How can I make an Android app installation to work similar as works installation from the official App Store for Android? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_software_distribution_platforms) Do I need to have Root access? Or should it be a special version of Android where App Store will work as Google Play? Currently, I’m only able to install applications as “Unknown Sources”, where my application downloads the apk File and calls a system installation window where user confirms the installation. The problem here is that the file to be installed can be copied (even just a brief moment). It may be ok for free applications or the ones with server authentication (log/pas) but for paid apps it could be a problem.

Comment: AFAIK, this is only possible as part of a custom OS build (e.g., ROM mod).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you install the app and delete the APK, it's still very easy to recover the APK of an installed application. The only way you can really protect your app is by using in-app licensing checks or locking the app to a certain device by using the device's id.

Further, on unrooted devices, you can not install apps outside of the Google Play store, unless you enable installation from unknown sources. To get around that restriction -- and to allow auto-updating or silent installation -- you will need to root and install a modified package manager.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I’m actually interested if it’s possible to make an Appstore client similar to Google Play?

Comment: Sure it is, with the caveats above. With a stock device, each update or install will prompt the user for confirmation. If you want to push silent installs, you'll need to implement that the long way.